# How Kafka dispatch message to multi-consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am testing how Kafka works on multi-consumers with high level Java APIS.

Created 1 topic with 5 partitions, 1 producer, and 2 consumer(`C1`, `C2`). Each consumer will have only one thread, and `partition.assignment.strategy` set to `range`.

`C1` start, it claim all the partition. Then `C2` start, ZK will trigger a rebalance. After that, `C1` will claim `(0, 1, 2)`, `C2` will claim `(3, 4)`. It works well util now.

Then I check the messages received by `C1`, I hope that messages will just from partitions `(0, 1, 2)`. But in my log file, I can find message from all the partitions, and that happened also in `C2`. It just like that `partition.assignment.strategy` set to `roundrobin`. Is this how Kafka dispatch message. Or that must be some mistake?

Comment: C1, C2 having separate group id ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all just to correct your approach, **Its always better to have same number of consumers as many partition you have for a topic**. In this way each Consumer will claim only one partition and will stick to that only and you will get exactly data from that partition and also in ordered way not from others.

Now to answer your question why you are getting data from almost all the partitions in both the **Consumer** because you have less consumers as compare to partitions in this case each Consumer thread will try to access partition.

There is also a theory that if you have greater number of **Consumers** as compared to number of partitions per topic then there is a possibility that some of the **Consumer** will never gets any data.